# Does Clojure have an efficient, idiomatic approach for decorators?

Tags: clojure, decorator, clojurescript

In Clojure(script) you define programming constructs with `deftype` and `defrecord`.  We want our constructs to each have a specific, well-defined purpose.  Rather than evolve any one construct into a monolithic full-featured thing, we choose to segregate responsibilities.  Decorators (e.g. data structures that wrap other data structures) are good for this.

For example, you have a logger construct.  You add timestamping as a feature with a decorator.  You later add alerting support staff beepers as another decorator.  We can, in theory, layer on any number of features this way.  Our config file cleanly determines which features get included.

If our logger implements a 3-method Logging protocol and each decorator only augments one, you still have to implement the other two methods on each decorator to uphold the contractual api.  These add-nothing implementations simply pass the message down the chain.  This is the awkward bit.

The richer a construct's api, the worse the problem.  Consider a construct that implements a few protocols and the work necessary to decorate something that handles 12 or so methods.

Is there a mechanism, macro, or technique that you've found to overcomes this?

Comment: One technique used to wrap data structures with other data structures, or indeed functions with other functions is called 'middleware'. Typically people come across it with Ring: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Concepts.

Comment: Middleware is great but from my experience it's designed for functions (e.g. contracts that deal with just 1 kind of message).  When you have a construct with potentially several methods (e.g. a protocol), is where the complication I mention comes about.  The question is: how to build middleware for constructs that support multiple methods without having to flesh out every method at every layer?

Comment: Middleware is exactly the decorator pattern, applied to functions. This question is about how to apply it to a "bundle" of multiple functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use `extend` to merge a mix of delegating-by-default functions and overriding implementations.

For example, with a logger protocol like:

```
(defprotocol Logger
  (info [logger s])
  (warn [logger s])
  (debug [logger s]))

(def println-logger
  (reify Logger
    (info [_ s]
      (println "Info:" s))
    (warn [_ s]
      (println "Warn:" s))
    (debug [_ s]
      (println "Debug:" s))))
```

You could write a function that creates decorator implementations like so:

```
(defn decorate-fn
  "Creates a decorator function
   given the implementation accessor and the called function."
  [impl f]
  (fn [decorator & args]
    (apply f (impl decorator) args)))

(defn gen-decorators
  "Creates a map of decorator functions."
  [impl fs]
  (into {} (for [[k f] fs]
             [k (decorate-fn impl f)])))

(defn decorate-logger
  "Creates a logger decorator with functions
   passing through to the implementation by default."
  [impl overrides]
  (merge (gen-decorators impl
                         {:info info
                          :warn warn
                          :debug debug})
         overrides))
```

And then use that to easily create decorators:

```
(defrecord CapslockWarningLogger [impl])

(extend CapslockWarningLogger
  Logger
  (decorate-logger :impl
                   {:warn (fn [{:keys [impl]} s]
                            (warn impl (clojure.string/upper-case s)))}))

(defrecord SelectiveDebugLogger [ignored impl])

(extend SelectiveDebugLogger
  Logger
  (decorate-logger :impl
                   {:debug (fn [{:keys [impl ignored]} s]
                             (when-not (ignored s)
                               (debug impl s)))}))

(def logger
  (->SelectiveDebugLogger #{"ignored"}
                          (->CapslockWarningLogger
                            println-logger)))

(info logger "something")
; Info: something
; => nil

(warn logger "something else")
; Warn: SOMETHING ELSE
; => nil

(debug logger "ignored")
; => nil
```

Comment: Ingenious.  It does do what I ask but it does require the adoption of this approach at the outset.  As I suspected, this was not a first-class problem that the language tried hard to address (e.g. `defdecorator`).  Thank you for the thoughtful reply.

Answer (score 3):

As a wildly different approach from using `extend`, it's not too hard to define a `defdecorator` macro that'll supply any missing protocol definitions by delegating to the decorated implementation.

Again, starting with a protocol like:

```
(defprotocol Logger
  (info [logger s])
  (warn [logger s])
  (debug [logger s]))

(def println-logger
  (reify Logger
    (info [_ s]
      (println "Info:" s))
    (warn [_ s]
      (println "Warn:" s))
    (debug [_ s]
      (println "Debug:" s))))
```

You can write some machinery to create protocol definitions by inspecting the protocol to get all of its functions, then creating delegating implementations for any that're missing:

```
(defn protocol-fn-matches?
  "Returns the protocol function definition
   if it matches the desired name and arglist."
  [[name arglist :as def] desired-name desired-arglist]
  (when (and (= name desired-name)
             (= (count arglist) (count desired-arglist)))
    def))

(defn genarglist
  "Takes an arglist and generates a new one with unique symbol names."
  [arglist]
  (mapv (fn [arg]
          (gensym (str arg)))
        arglist))

(defn get-decorator-definitions
  "Generates the protocol functions for a decorator,
   defaulting to forwarding to the implementation if
   a function is not overwritten."
  [protocol-symbol impl fs]
  (let [protocol-var (or (resolve protocol-symbol)
                         (throw (Exception. (str "Unable to resolve protocol: " protocol-symbol))))
        protocol-ns (-> protocol-var meta :ns)
        protocol (var-get protocol-var)]
    (for [{:keys [name arglists]} (vals (:sigs protocol))
          arglist arglists]
      (or (some #(protocol-fn-matches? % name arglist) fs)
          (let [arglist (genarglist arglist) ; Generate unique names to avoid collision
                forwarded-args (rest arglist) ; Drop the "this" arg
                f (symbol (str protocol-ns) (str name))] ; Get the function in the protocol namespace
            `(~name ~arglist
               (~f ~impl ~@forwarded-args)))))))
```

You can then write a macro that takes the definitions and creates a record extending the given protocols, using `get-decorator-definitions` to supply any missing definitions:

```
(defmacro defdecorator
  [type-symbol fields impl & body]
  (let [provided-protocols-and-defs (->> body
                                         (partition-by symbol?)
                                         (partition-all 2))
        protocols-and-defs (mapcat (fn [[[protocol] fs]]
                                     (cons protocol
                                           (get-decorator-definitions protocol impl fs)))
                                   provided-protocols-and-defs)]
    `(defrecord ~type-symbol ~fields
       ~@protocols-and-defs)))
```

And use it to create new decorators:

```
(defdecorator CapslockWarningLogger
              [impl] impl
              Logger
              (warn [_ s]
                    (warn impl (clojure.string/upper-case s))))

(defdecorator SelectiveDebugLogger
              [ignored impl] impl
              Logger
              (debug [_ s]
                     (when-not (ignored s)
                       (debug impl s))))
```

Comment: Incredible.  Thanks for the effort.  I will have to investigate further.